# get coordinates of arrow of a line point

Tags: vector

Consider I have 2 points.

QPoint(100,100)
QPoint(200,200)

Now, I need to draw a pointed arrow at the end of line QPoint(200,200).

How can I get the points of the arrow coordinates since the line is in inclined angle? The arrow should be like given below.

[image]

As this is more a general question, Im tagging on pyqt5 and css.

Comment: Trigonometry. Determine the angle of the line segment relative to the end point (in this case 225). Then choose the angle of each of "arrow wings" and the length of each, for example 30 degrees and 20 length. 225+/-30 = 195, 255. Find the endpoints on the circle at 200,200 with a radius of 20 and angles 195, 255. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260096/find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the slope of your line, which will let you find a point on the line a given distance from your endpoint. You can then build a a new line perpendicular to the original line that goes through the point. The ends of the arrows should lie on that line a given distance from the original. It's easier to show than explain:

```js
function draw(point1, point2, distance, length) {
  // slope is dx/dy
  let dx = point2[0] - point1[0]
  let dy = point2[1] - point1[1]
  let v_norm = Math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)

  // point on line at distance
  let point_on_line = [point2[0] - distance * dx / v_norm, point2[1] - distance * dy / v_norm]

  // endpoints of arrows at length above point (the distance from the original line
  let point_below = [point_on_line[0] - length * -dy / v_norm, point_on_line[1] - length * dx / v_norm, ]
  let point_above = [point_on_line[0] + length * -dy / v_norm, point_on_line[1] + length * dx / v_norm, ]

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(...point1);
  ctx.lineTo(...point2);
  ctx.moveTo(...point_above)
  ctx.lineTo(...point2)
  ctx.lineTo(...point_below)
  ctx.stroke();
}

draw([100, 100], [200, 150], 20, 10)
draw([100, 100], [300, 150], 20, 10)
draw([100, 100], [150, 10], 20, 10)
draw([100, 100], [90, 150], 20, 10)
draw([100, 100], [200, 100], 20, 10)
draw([100, 100], [5, 10], 20, 10)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width='500' height='500'></canvas>
```

You can alter the shape of the arrows using `distance` and `length`

Comment: Thanks for your comments it was very helpful, I posted a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408533/calculating-a-point-on-the-same-slope-of-a-line

Comment: how come the arrow always have something that protrudes from it instead of a sharp pointed arrow?

Comment: Thank you very much buddy for putting this question. I have been looking for a solution for my problem, and now I just get the idea how I have to do it. Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 0):

If we have a look at the points we need (U and D needed, S and E given):

```
      U
     /|
   /  |    
S---------------------E
   \  |
     \|
      D
```

We actually have to go back from S to E, then we turn by 90 degrees and walk up the same length. If we take the direction between S and E (represented as Vectors):

```
d = E - S
```

Then we can get the distance to walk back:

```
b = -d / 4
```

And then to walk up in a 90 degree angle, we just swap x and y, to go down we just take the negative one:

```
u = [b.y, b.x]
d = -u
```

So we can finally get our points as:

```
U = S + b + u
D = S + b + d
```

*(The code above is pseudocode as you wanted a general solution)*

Comment: Thanks..What happens if the line is not at 90 degrees..Is there any python package that can automatically calculate it for me.

Comment: I cannot answer that as asking for libraries is a bit off-topic and I don't know python :) But you can easily scale down `u` and `d` to achieve this.